# Which Schema Should I Use for Ferry Travel?

Tags: seo, markup

I need some help on which schema to  use.

These pages aren't live yet, but I want to brief our developers on schema when we start to build them.

Page Example - Ferries to Jersey

The pages will  have the following information -

- Routes/Ports we sail from
- No. of sailings/duration/latest offers/ship - in a table format
- Map of routes
- Travel advice - linking to other important areas on the site to help with travel

Comment: do you mean Schema.org markup? Or something else?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO" but there is no general SEO benefit to finding some schema to use.   The only search engine benefit from schema is when Google uses that schema to show an enhanced display in the search results.   Most schema don't get that treatment, so there is no SEO benefit to using it.  Google has a list of schema they use in their search gallery.  If it isn't on that list, there is no SEO benefit: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery

Comment: Thank you I will review the list. I want to enhance our search results listings as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this question is about structured data, [the event structure](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/event) seems to be the closest to what you describe.

You can see the full details [in the relevant schema.org page](https://schema.org/Event)

> An event happening at a certain time and location, such as a concert, lecture, or festival. Ticketing information may be added via the offers property. Repeated events may be structured as separate Event objects.